# How to render a string attribute as URL in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Following a RoR turorial where I am building a basic bookmark app.

I have two models, `topic` and `bookmark`.

Bookmarks have a `url` attribute. The `url` attribute is rendering fine on my `topics#show`, but as plain text. When I tried to render it as a link it doesn't link to the url properly.

How do I render it as a hyperlink?

I have tried this

```
<%= @topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
<a href="#{bookmark.url}">bookmark.url</a>
<% end %>
```

But clearly that doesn't look right. Am I interpolating the correct way?

Alternatively is there a rails helper method that would do the trick?

Here are my files

Topics controller

class TopicsController < ApplicationController

```
 def index
   @topics = Topic.all
 end

 def new
   @topic = Topic.new
 end

 def show
   @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])  
 end

 def create
   @topic = Topic.new(params.require(:topic).permit(:name))
   if @topic.save
     redirect_to @topic
   else
     render :new
   end
 end
```

end

My bookmarks controller

class BookmarksController < ApplicationController

```
 def create
   @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
   @bookmarks = @topic.bookmarks
   @bookmark = @topic.bookmarks.build(params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url, :topic_id))
   @bookmark.topic = @topic
   @new_bookmark = Bookmark.new
   if @bookmark.save
     flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was saved"
     redirect_to @topic
   else
     flash[:error] = "There was an error, please try again later"
     redirect_to @topic
   end
 end

 def destroy
   @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
   @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
   @bookmark.topic = @topic

   if @bookmark.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was destroyed successfully"
     redirect_to [@topic]
   else
     flash[:error] = "There was an error, please try again later"
   end
 end
```

end

And these are my migration files

```
class CreateTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :topics do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateBookmarks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bookmarks do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.references :topic, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



  resources :topics do
    resources :bookmarks, only: [:destroy, :create]
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'



  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Bookmark form partial which is displayed in `topics#show`

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @topic.bookmarks.new] do |f| %>
 <div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: "Enter bookmark url", class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
    <%= f.submit "save", class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

in `topics#show` added this line to render partial

```
<%= render partial: 'bookmarks/form', locals: { topic: @topic, bookmark: @bookmark} %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use the helper `link_to`?

`<%= link_to 'name', bookmark.url, class: 'btn btn-default' %>`

Comment: That's a separate issue. Assuming you have a bookmark object with a  valid URL, ```link_to``` should be working fine.

Comment: I used <%= link_to bookmark.url, bookmark.url %> because other wise all my links, or in the above code's case, a button, will render with "name" instead of the link name.

Comment: Well.. yes. The code I posted was an example; the first argument to ```link_to``` is what gets displayed as the link text in the output. 'name' was just a placeholder.

Comment: Yes, I know. But there was another user who gave me the code in context with my problem before I realized that I had to prefix 'https://' thanks to you! The answer to the my issue was all over the place. So wanted to make it clear in case anyone else had the problem! Thanks a ton again!

Answer (score 1):

ERB does not interpolate strings unless they are inside ERB blocks (`<%` ... `%>`).

I.e., in your case the following would work:

```
<a href="<%= bookmark.url %>">bookmark.url</a>
```

The cleaner solution is to use `link_to` as was mentioned in another answer. I just thought it's important to understand why the original solution did not work.

Comment: I entered `<a href="<%= bookmark.url %>"><%= bookmark.url %></a>`

But I got a routing error - `No route matches [GET] "/topics/www.google.com"`

Comment: You should check the contents of bookmark.url. Try adding `<% p bookmark.url %>` and check the console output.

Comment: Is that the same as `<p><%= bookmark.url %></p>`? Because the string is being rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `link_to` helper method:

```
<%= @topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
  <%= link_to bookmark.url, bookmark.url %>
<% end %>
```

More info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: I got the error `No route matches [GET] "/topics/www.google.com"`.

Comment: Just added it int he question!

Comment: @deventhusiast you need to make sure that URLs are saved with the ```http://``` prefix, otherwise the URL will be treated as relative to your server's root.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing if you don't mind - How do I make the target open in a new tab? And what is the helper equivalent of this. `<a href="<%= bookmark.url target="_blank"%>"><%= bookmark.url %>'?

Comment: the ```link_to``` helper accepts a hash as the last argument, so whatever key-value pair you provide will be translateD into attribute="..." in the output, so I'm guessing you can do ```<%= link_to 'name', bookmark.url, target: '_blank' %>```